# How to count cells that are within 2 values, in a range of cells in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, optimization

I have a dataframe that looks like that:

```
    col1
0     10
1      5
2      8
3     12
4     13
5      6
6      9
7     11
8     10
9      3
10    21
11    18
12    14
13    16
14    30
15    45
16    31
17    40
18    38
```

For each cell in 'col1' I calculate a range of values:

```
df['df_min'] = df.col1 - df.col1 * 0.2
df['df_max'] = df.col1 + df.col1 * 0.2
```

For each cell there's a range, I would like to count how many cells in 'col1' in the past xx cells (3 in this example) are within that range, but without a loop as it takes a very long time with my actual model.

I'm trying to achieve this result:

```
    col1  df_min  df_max  counter
0     10     8.0    12.0       -1
1      5     4.0     6.0       -1
2      8     6.4     9.6       -1
3     12     9.6    14.4        1
4     13    10.4    15.6        1
5      6     4.8     7.2        0
6      9     7.2    10.8        0
7     11     8.8    13.2        2
8     10     8.0    12.0        2
9      3     2.4     3.6        0
10    21    16.8    25.2        0
11    18    14.4    21.6        1
12    14    11.2    16.8        0
13    16    12.8    19.2        2
14    30    24.0    36.0        0
15    45    36.0    54.0        0
16    31    24.8    37.2        1
17    40    32.0    48.0        1
18    38    30.4    45.6        3
```

Here's the (messy) code that I could come up with, but I'd really like a faster solution, if possible. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[10, 5, 8, 12, 13, 6, 9, 11, 10, 3, 21, 18, 14, 16, 30, 45, 31, 40, 38]})

back = 3 # numbers of cells to check back

df['df_min'] = df.col1 - df.col1 * 0.2
df['df_max'] = df.col1 + df.col1 * 0.2

l = []
for window in df.col1.rolling(window=back+1, center=False, closed='right'):
    if window.empty:
        pass
    else:
        a = window.iloc[-1]
        range_min = a - a * 0.2
        range_max = a + a * 0.2
        c = 0
        if len(window) == back+1:
            for b in window:
                if (b >= range_min and b <= range_max):
                    c += 1
        c = c-1 # substract 1 because window includes the tested value which is always true
        l.append(c)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['counter'])

df = df.join(df1)

print(df)
```

Comment: I think this can be done with pandas filters

Comment: How many rows do you have in the real dataset?

Comment: About 300,000 rows and I have to run this function several times. With the solution of @Panda Kim, running his function 4 times with n = 150 takes less than 0.5s.

Answer (score 2):

loop with vectorization operation

**Code**

```
df['df_min'] = df.col1 - df.col1 * 0.2
df['df_max'] = df.col1 + df.col1 * 0.2
n = 3
s = pd.Series(dtype='float')
for i in range(0, n):
    s1 = df.col1.shift(i+1).ge(df['df_min']) & df.col1.shift(i+1).le(df['df_max'])
    s = s.add(s1, fill_value=0)
s[:n] = -1
df['counter'] = s
```

output(`df`):

```
    col1    df_min  df_max  counter
0   10      8.0     12.0    -1.0
1   5       4.0     6.0     -1.0
2   8       6.4     9.6     -1.0
3   12      9.6     14.4    1.0
4   13      10.4    15.6    1.0
5   6       4.8     7.2     0.0
6   9       7.2     10.8    0.0
7   11      8.8     13.2    2.0
8   10      8.0     12.0    2.0
9   3       2.4     3.6     0.0
10  21      16.8    25.2    0.0
11  18      14.4    21.6    1.0
12  14      11.2    16.8    0.0
13  16      12.8    19.2    2.0
14  30      24.0    36.0    0.0
15  45      36.0    54.0    0.0
16  31      24.8    37.2    1.0
17  40      32.0    48.0    1.0
18  38      30.4    45.6    3.0
```

i don know your dataset. However, when im testing with 1,000,000 rows and `n = 10`, this code takes only 0.4sec.

**test example**

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20,100, 1000000), columns=['col1'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, easy to read function and very fast (0.465s on my model). Beautiful solution, greatly appreciated!

Comment: I also made code by `rolling` at first, but I changed it to run faster because I didn't know your dataset. `rolling` is also a good function, so use it well.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html). From the tests I did on my computer, this solution appears to be very fast and efficient, even for large datasets.

```
n = 3

df['counter'] = (df['col1'].rolling(n+1)
                 .apply(lambda x: 
                     np.sum((x[:n] >= (x[n] * 0.8)) & (x[:n] <= (x[n] * 1.2))), 
                     raw=True).fillna(-1).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
    col1  df_min  df_max  counter
0     10     8.0    12.0       -1
1      5     4.0     6.0       -1
2      8     6.4     9.6       -1
3     12     9.6    14.4        1
4     13    10.4    15.6        1
5      6     4.8     7.2        0
6      9     7.2    10.8        0
7     11     8.8    13.2        2
8     10     8.0    12.0        2
9      3     2.4     3.6        0
10    21    16.8    25.2        0
11    18    14.4    21.6        1
12    14    11.2    16.8        0
13    16    12.8    19.2        2
14    30    24.0    36.0        0
15    45    36.0    54.0        0
16    31    24.8    37.2        1
17    40    32.0    48.0        1
18    38    30.4    45.6        3
```

Comment: Very nice solution indeed, using the .rolling function. Surprisingly a bit slower than the loop solution from @Panda Kim but I definitely keep this format for further usage. Thanks all for your help and teachings!